# Akka durable mailbox lose messages before the message has been processed?

Tags: transactions, message, akka

the Akka [durable mailbox document](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/modules/durable-mailbox.html) statements that:

> A durable mailbox is like any other mailbox not likely to be transactional. It's possible if the actor crashes after receiving a message, but before completing processing of it, that the message could be lost.

Suppose actor A uses durable mailbox as message queue, and the queue has 2 messages, M1, and M2. the actor received M1 and is processing M1. if A crashes before finishing processing M1, is M1 lost? A related questions is what does mean 'A crashes': does it mean A got uncaught exception or the JVM running A crashes?

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for a crash could be anything, the term is meant to signify that processing did not finish (either interrupted by an exception or terminated in the middle by a power outage or anything else in between). As soon as the actor has dequeued the message from the mailbox, it is gone from the mailbox. If you do not want that behavior, you’ll have to implement something like [the peek mailbox](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-contrib/src/main/scala/akka/contrib/mailbox/PeekMailbox.scala), see [the docs here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/contrib/peek-mailbox.html).

Comment: i read the peek mailbox API as well as the sample code in the docs. the sample calls ack() on the mailbox instead of individual messages. if two messages M1 and M2 from the mailbox are in the middle of processing at beginning. if processing M1 is done and M2 is still being processed by another actor, and the actor calls mailbox.ack(), does it mean both M1 and M2 will be removed from the mailbox?

Comment: The mailbox is private to each actor, there cannot be two messages "active" at any time.